# String with spaces when concatenate

Tags: jquery

I'm using .get() for getting a view and i have to concatenate two variables in the path but when i do that path stay with a lot of spaces. The variables values are well received from two drop downs.

the problem is that:

```
function getTableData(){
 $( "#getTable" ).click(function(e){
   table = $('#tabax').val();
   type = $('#type').val();
   alert(table);
   alert(type);
   alert("upload-file/tb/"+table+"/"+type);
   $.get("upload-file/tb/"+table+"/"+type, function(response){
      $('.table-data').html(response);
   });
   e.preventDefault();
 });}
```

my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('tabax', 'Table:') !!}
      {!! Form::select('tabax', $tabax, null, ['id'=> 'tabax', 'class' => 'form-control tabax']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('type', 'Type:') !!}
      {!! Form::select('type', $type, null, ['id'=> 'type', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
```

and the path is:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/upload-file/tb/FT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/1
```

I do not know why it happens, i'm doing this a lot and this is the first time that i have this problem.

Comment: Without knowing what you are posting (which is obv taken from HTML), we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly values in those tables appear from CHAR(n) SQL fields, which automatically up-filled with spaces. If you have access to the server I suggest to change field types to VARCHAR(n) and migrate data trimming values, this way you will reduce client-server traffic.

Otherwise you can trim them on client side (replace lines 3 and 4):

```
table = $('#tabax').val().trim();
type = $('#type').val().trim();
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using SQL and the problem should be this. With trim() works fine.
Thanks @MaxVorobjev

Answer (score 1):

To replace the spaces in the string, use a global regular expression replacement which matches whitespace characters:

```
table = table.replace(/\s+/g, "");
```

Ideally the whitespace would not be in the string to start with, but to comment on that you'll need to include the HTML for tabax.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas , this also works.